# Differential Free Shipping

Tags: customer-group, free-shipping

We are using magento for our retail as well as distributor ordering.

There are customer groups made and the free shipping applies after certain amount.

Retail Buyer : 
Min order value - Rs. 500 else Rs. 200 is charged extra

Distributor :
Min order value - Rs. 85000 else Rs. 3500 is charged extra

How can this be achieved?

Thanks in advance.

Kartik

Answer (score 0):

First of all create shipping method with cost 3500.

Then described logic can be achieved by creating Shopping Cart Price Rules.

First rule:

- Customer Groups: Retail Buyer
- Conditions: Subtotal less than 500
- Actions: Apply - Fixed amount discount; Discount Amount 3300 (it is 3500-200); Apply to Shipping Amount - Yes

Second rule:

- Customer Groups: Retail Buyer
- Conditions: Subtotal equals or greater than 500
- Actions: Free Shipping - For shipment with matching items

Third rule:

- Customer Groups: Distributor
- Conditions: Subtotal equals or greater than 85000
- Actions: Free Shipping - For shipment with matching items

Other solution may be to install an extension providing different shipping methods for Customer Groups, and then create onlu 2nd and 3rd rule.